# Why does EBS volume mount on /dev/sdj rather than /dev/sdf?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I created an EBS volume and attached it to a CentOS instance on /dev/sdf.
From within the instance, I see it appear as /dev/sdj.

Any explanations for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kernel will map the device you specify depending on the drivers installed in order to avoid namespace clashes. For example most of the Ubuntu kernels I have used map `/dev/sdf` to `/dev/xvdf`.

According to [this post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=454116) what you are seeing is likely an artifact from [a RHEL6.1 kernel change](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=729586), where they intentionally remap xen drives as X+4.

Comment: Alright then, not a bug, but a feature.